# redis and resque in production

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I want to get resque background processing working in production on my centos server for a rails 3 application.

I then want to monitor redis and resque with bluepill.

What is the best way to install redis in production for resque and also has anyone get a .pill file for redis and resque ?

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 0):

The Linode Library has a nice article about [installing Redis in CentOS 5](http://library.linode.com/databases/redis/centos-5), and [Resque's Github page](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) is an excellent resource for Resque.

Redis Bluepill:

```
Bluepill.application("app-name") do |app|
  app.process("redis") do |process|
  process.start_command = "redis-server /path/to/redis.conf"
  process.daemonize = true
  process.pid_file = "/tmp/redis.pid"
  process.start_grace_time = 3.seconds
  process.stop_grace_time = 5.seconds
  process.restart_grace_time = 8.seconds
end
```

Bluepill's syntax is fairly straight-forward and I'll leave the .pill for Resque for you to try :)

Answer (score 0):

A few of my notes on the linode Redis article:

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/redis/redis-on-centos-5/

When wgetting redis:
You could link directly to the latest stable version of redis:

`wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make`

- redis user needs to own the pid directory to write the pid, otherwise it'll silently fail in daemon mode:

`mkdir /var/run/redis
chown redis:redis /var/run/redis`

- then direct creation of pid to the new directoy in the `init.d` script as well as the `redis.conf` file:

`/var/run/redis/redis.pid` as opposed to `/var/run/redis.pid`